# How do I evaluate the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\ln\big(1+\frac{1}{k+a}\right)-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k+b}\big)\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, logarithms, infinite-product

How do I evaluate the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\ln\Big(1+\frac{1}{k+a}
\Big)-\ln\Big(1+\frac{1}{k+b}\Big)\right)$$

where $0 <a<b<1$?

Hints will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @luka5z edited thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k+a}\right)=\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\Big(1+\frac{1}{k+a}\Big)\right)=\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k+1+a}{k+a}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{n+1+a}{1+a}\right)
$$
and thus
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k+a}\right)-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k+b}\right)=
\ln\left(\frac{n+1+a}{1+a}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{n+1+b}{1+b}\right) \\=\ln\left(\frac{1+b}{1+a}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{n+1+b}{n+1+a}\right)\to \ln\left(\frac{1+b}{1+a}\right),
$$
as $n\to\infty$, since
$$
\ln\left(\frac{n+1+b}{n+1+a}\right)=\ln\left(1+\frac{b-a}{n+1+a}\right)\to 0.
$$

Comment: But answer is not 0.

Comment: @Fabian You are right. I corrected it.

Comment: @TaylorTed I didn't get $0$ as an answer, but $\ln(\frac{1+b}{1+a})$.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis i am not getting how summation is changed into product

Comment: @TaylorTed Since $\sum \ln a_i=\ln a_1+\cdots +\ln a_n=\ln (a_1\cdots a_n)=\ln (\prod a_i)$.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$S_n = \ln\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k+a+1}{k+a} - \ln\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k+b+1}{k+b}= \ln\dfrac{k+a+1}{a+1} - \ln\dfrac{k+b+1}{b+1}$$$$ = \ln\dfrac{b+1}{a+1} + \ln\dfrac{k+b+1}{k+a+1}.$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k+a}\right)-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k+b}\right) = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} S_n = \ln\dfrac{b+1}{a+1} +\ln1 =\ln\dfrac{b+1}{a+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that, for each fixed $k$, $\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k+a}\right)-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k+b}\right)=\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\frac{1}{k+a}}{1+\frac{1}{k+b}}\right)$. Then:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k+a}\right)-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k+b}\right)&=&\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\frac{1}{k+a}}{1+\frac{1}{k+b}}\right)\\
&=&\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1+\frac{1}{k+a}}{1+\frac{1}{k+b}}\right)\\
&=&\ln\left(\dfrac{\frac{n+a+1}{a+1}}{\frac{n+b+1}{b+1}}\right)\\
&=&\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\frac{n}{a+1}}{1+\frac{n}{b+1}}\right)\\
&=&\ln\left(\dfrac{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{a+1}}{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{b+1}}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus, taking $n\to\infty$, the limit is $\ln(b+1)-\ln(a+1)$

Comment: Why summation is changed into product

Comment: Properties of log of a product: $\ln(xy)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$, where $x,y>0$, and it extends to a finite number of summands (that´s the reason for we take first the sum from $k=1$ to $n$ and finally take limit)